# Regarding connection class in RethinkDb

Tags: database, flutter, rethinkdb, reql

I am not able to understand why am I getting this error stating that connection of type Connection is not initialized if anyone could help me out with it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFYU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main method, you are writing

```
Connection connection; // connection is still null
UserService sut = UserService(r, connection);
```

But as you error message said : you cannot instantiate `UserService` with a `connection` variable that is null.
You must rework your code so your variable won't be null when you initialize the UserService